# Type mismatch error using 'AdvanceFilter'

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to automate an AdvancedFilter for multiple sheets within a workbook. However, I am running into `Type Mismatch` and I cannot find what needs to be changed, since stepping through just highlights the whole block of code. The error shown is:

> Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    For Each ws In Array(Worksheets("test"), Worksheets("test1"), Worksheets("test2"), Worksheets("test3"), Worksheets("test4"))
        ws.Activate
        Sheets("Main").Range("A:J").AdvanceFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
            CriteriaRange:=Sheets(ws).Range("A1:A2"), CopyToRange:=Sheets(ws).Range("A3"), Unique:=False
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try adding Dim ws As Worksheet before the loop?

Comment: Wouldn't need to, the for loop creates it. But when I do `Dim ws As Worksheet` it throws a `run-time 424 Object required`

Comment: The criteria is defined on each sheet? it seems like your criteria is encompassed in the range you are filtering

Comment: Yea each sheet has the  almost the same criteria. The only difference is each worksheet is filtered for that name. eg Worksheet("test") filters everything that has the "test" characteristic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your AdvancedFilter line with this:

```
Sheets("Main").Range("A:J").AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, ws.Range("A1:A2"), ws.Range("A3")
```